# How do I move data scraped with Beautifulsoup to a MySQL database?

Tags: python, mysql, beautifulsoup

I am a newbie to Beautifulsoup and I've been trying to load individual td items to a MySQL table. How do I separate each td to be able to then populate to the MySQL table?

I have tried to break things down by td tag, but I'm doing something wrong there as well.

```
html_url = 'https://markets.wsj.com/'
html_doc = urllib.request.urlopen(html_url).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
markets = soup.find(id='majorStockIndexes_moduleId')

marketRows = markets.tbody.find_all('tr')

for row in marketRows:
    for column in row.find_all('td'):
        print(column.text)
        columnType = column.text

query = "INSERT INTO MarketData1 (recordID, stock, last, priceChange, percentChange) VALUES (NULL, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
arguments = (stockName, lastValue, priceChange, percentChange)
```

I am trying to get the following td classes to match up with the following arguments:

td class "firstCol"  - stockName
td class "dataCol"   - lastValue
td class "dataCol priceDown   - priceChange
td class "dataCol last priceDown  - percentChange

Comment: *I keep getting errors* then also include the errors so we know what’s going on. Errors aren’t there just for fun, they explain what is going wrong. And I don’t see any ifs in this code either. So please show what you’ve tried to get it to do what you want

Comment: always show full error message (Traceback) in question. `td` is not class but tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will help you, you just need to configure your MySQL credentials.

```
import urllib
import mysql.connector
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_url = 'https://markets.wsj.com/'
html_doc = urllib.request.urlopen(html_url).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
markets = soup.find(id='majorStockIndexes_moduleId')

marketRows = markets.tbody.find_all('tr')


mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd="root",
    database="mydatabase"
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()


for column in marketRows:
    stockName = column.find('td',class_='firstCol').text.strip()
    lastValue = column.find('td',class_='dataCol').text
    priceChange = column.find('td',class_='priceDown').text
    percentChange = column.find('td',class_='last').text

    print("stockname :",stockName)
    print('lastValue :',lastValue)
    print("priceChange :",priceChange)
    print("percentChange :",percentChange)
    print()

    query = "INSERT INTO MarketData1 (recordID, stock, last, priceChange, percentChange) VALUES (NULL, %s, %s, %s, %s)"

    arguments = (stockName, lastValue, priceChange, percentChange)

    mycursor.execute(query, arguments)

    mydb.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

`row.find_all('td')` gives you list with all `td` in row so you have to only convert to list with text from every `td`

```
    all_td = row.find_all('td')
    arguments = [x.text.strip() for x in all_td]
```

and then you have arguments for `INSERT`

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_url = 'https://markets.wsj.com/'
html_doc = urllib.request.urlopen(html_url).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
markets = soup.find(id='majorStockIndexes_moduleId')

marketRows = markets.tbody.find_all('tr')

for row in marketRows:
    all_td = row.find_all('td')
    arguments = [x.text.strip() for x in all_td]
    print(arguments)
    # ... here INSERT data to database ...
```

Displayed data

```
['DJIA', '26150.58', '-190.44', '-0.72%']
['Nasdaq', '7909.28', '-44.61', '-0.56%']
['S&P 500', '2878.20', '-17.57', '-0.61%']
['Russell 2000', '1559.68', '-19.32', '-1.22%']
['Global Dow', '3061.02', '-4.21', '-0.14%']
['Japan: Nikkei 225', '21653.01', '-149.58', '-0.69%']
['Stoxx Europe 600', '385.68', '-1.83', '-0.47%']
['UK: FTSE 100', '7425.57', '-26.32', '-0.35%']
```